# Get the name of the table column referenced by a (auto updatable) view column (PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql, view, information-schema

Given the folowing view definition

```
create or replace view projects as
select id, client_id as clientId from data.projects
```

Is it possible, knowing the view name and the view column to get the name of the original table and column names?

I know about information_schema.view_column_usage but it does not provide the column to column relation.
My thinking is that although it might not be possible to find out using a query, the information is available somehow since the column `clientId` is autoupdatable and PG needs to somehow translate it to an insert on the original table.

Is there a public function similar to `pg_column_is_updatable` that would return the `oid` of the referenced column?

**EDIT:**
The best i could come up with is this https://gist.github.com/ruslantalpa/2eab8c930a65e8043d8f

Comment: I would settle also for the name of the source table (invormation_schema.view_table_usage does not work since it also lists the tables that are used in where clause)

Comment: Just as suggestion: try `explain verbose select client_id from projects`. I am not big fun of views so I can not test it quickly but I believe that result contains info about what comes from where.

Comment: There is something there but it does not really help, i would have to resort to text parsing. I am trying to come up with a query like information_schema.view_column_usage but with an additional column that contains the name of the column in the view

Comment: This is related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048056/find-the-real-column-name-of-an-alias-used-in-a-view but it's for sqlserver. There seems to be a relation between sqlserver sys and pg's pg_class schemas, but it's a bit hard for me to translate the query while not very familiar with sys or pg_class

Comment: If I understand something in DBMS... Views is not something static but just alias for subqueries. For example, `create view v as select * from t` and `select * from v where id = 1` does not mean that DBMS builds the copy of table `t` and then searches in it for the condition provided. View usage can be investigated only in the context of the query using it. IMO.

Comment: And another simple example: `select case when t0.x>0 then t1.y else t2.y end as foo from t0 natural join t1 natural join t2` Where is field `foo` comes from?

Comment: @Abelisto i understand what you are saying but take a look at information_schema.view_column_usage and also think about if you have a table and a view based on that table, and you want to alter the name of a column from the table, you get a error. I.e. without "running the view query" PG knows exactly that something (the view) depends on a particular column in the table. This is the information i want to find out.

Comment: `create view v as select t1.* from t1 natural join t2` Here is `t2` table does not provides any data but used in view. I trying just to point that it is impossible (in general) to provide static info about view's columns. So your question (I guess) has no answer.

Comment: @Abelisto i would not go as far as impossible since things like autoupdatable views exist, so in some cases, PG know exactly the relation between a view column and table column but i can maybe agree with the statement "pg_catalog" does not provide such info. Still, one can try ... here is what i got this far https://gist.github.com/ruslantalpa/2eab8c930a65e8043d8f There are still some bad rows there but it's better then nothing.

Comment: Probably you mean something like `triggers on vews`?

Comment: Maybe `pg_depend` contains that information. But it's really ugly to work with

Comment: I was hoping that too but i could not find it. It seems to only have table-column dependency, not column-column. I would be glad if i am wrong :) since the regexp method is quite ugly

Comment: I used queries/views from here https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Pg_depend_display too look if the info is available, maybe they somehow omit the column-column relations